# iOS: Stop Photos app from opening automatically after receiving photos via AirDrop

Tags: iphone, ios

When i send some pictures to my iPhone from my MacBook via AirDrop, the Photos app on my iPhone opens automatically.

How can I stop that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

iOS is programmed to automatically open the default handler app after it receives file(s)/data via AirDrop.

There is no native way built into iOS to change this behaviour.

Comment: I have the same question. Is there a way to change the default handler app?